# I try to run an executable file on a cluster which is compiled with cpp. But I meet some erros just like below

Tags: c++, cluster-computing, qsub

I use the command qsub and submit my shell to the node.Some errors happende just like this

[image]

And this is my pbs filr named submit. I cant figure out what probelms had happened

```
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -N test
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -V
#PBS -o /home/wyhao/output/out/screen.out
#PBS -e /home/wyhao/output/error/error.err
#PBS -l walltime=99:23:59:59


# export PATH=$PATH:/share/apps/mpich/bin
# export PATH=$PATH:/home/wyhao/cmake-3.10/bi
export PATH=/usr/lib64:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
source /share/apps/mpich 
source /home/wyhao/dealii-8.4.1


# Nprocs=`qstat -xf $PBS_JOBID | grep List.ncpus | sed 's/^.\{26\}//'`
# cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
# echo "Job $PBS_JOBID started at `date` on `hostname` using $Nprocs processors"


cd /home/wyhao/single-ST/build
# mkdir build
# cmake -DDEAL_II_DIR=/home/wyhao/dealii-8.4.0 ../
# make
# /share/apps/mpich/bin/mpiexec -n 8 ./R0.5-0.2K-r2.41-ST
/share/apps/mpich/bin/mpiexec -f hosts -n 8 $PBS_NODEFILE ./R0.5-0.2K-r2.41-ST`
```

R0.5-0.2K-r2.41-ST is the file name of my executable file.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Looks like your problem happens after C++, so you might want to use a different tag to attract better-suited eyes. `mpi` looks like a decent candidate, but you should read the tag wiki and the mpi-related tags first to make sure it's the best fit.